# Proper way of adding parameters to a test wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, variational-principle

So experimenting with the variational method, I thought of a test wave function for an infinite deep well system,
$$\Psi(x) = N(a^2-x^2) \text{ for $-a$ < $x$ < $a$}$$
and $0$ everywhere else.

Now, this function is well-behaved and non-existent at the boundaries of the well as it should be in the case of the infinite deep well. To obtain the eigenvalues from this function as close as possible to the real eigenvalues $E_n = \pi^2 \hbar^2/(8ma^2)$ for the infinite well, I decided to add arbitrary parameters to the trial wave function and then using the variational method, find the extremum wrt the parameter and continue to find the eigenvalue of the obtained wave function.

I understand that we can do this owing the completeness property of the set of wave functions of the system. So my questions regarding this procedure are as follows:

1. What is the **correct** way to add these parameters to the wave function? I tried doing the following:
   $$(a^2-x^2)\to(a-\lambda x)(a+x)$$ where $\lambda$ is an arbitrary parameter wrt whom the Hamiltonian ($\hat{H}$) of the system is to be minimised.
   But it results in obtaining the same energy eigenvalue as in the case of $a^x - x^2$.

   I tried doing $a^2 - \lambda^2 x^2$ but that makes the matter even worse by making $\lambda$ a very high number.
2. And second, do we have to normalize the wave function in general after adding a parameter to it, i.e., will the normalization constant of $a^2 - x^2$ differ from $(a-\lambda x)(a+x)$?

Comment: When you say you tried $a^x-\lambda^2x^2$, you mean $a^2-\lambda^2x^2$, right?

Comment: Have you tried plotting your trial wavefunctions and comparing them to the known ground state of the infinite square well? You may be able to work out what is happening